# What does M,O stand for

Tags: abbreviations

Reading this article, there is a line,

> While many fans who watched The Last Dance appreciated The Worm’s, uh, free-spiritedness, there is another section of fans who found his actions unprofessional and irresponsible. And they would have every right to feel that way, because, well, that’s certainly been Rodman’s **M.O.** over the years.

I guess that would mean "my opinion".(I noticed while writing this question.)

---

If you google "M.O my opinion", the only result is IMO, in my opinion, which I am sure used to.

Please confirm that M.O is **not** the other meanings such as (from Collins)

> mainly US
>   abbreviation for money order US
>
> abbreviation for medical officer

Thank you for your time you spend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"M.O." stands for [modus operandi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_operandi), which is a Latin phrase that literally means "way of operating." In casual English, it means "the usual way a specific person does a particular activity." The really important part of that definition is "specific person." You don't use it to describe the typical way *any person* would do something; you use M.O. when you're talking about one person's distinctive methods.

Why Latin? The phrase almost certainly emerged from the legal profession, where Latin phrases are frequently used. From there, it also became used in criminology and police work, where a criminal's **M.O.** is their particular way of accomplishing a repeat crime.  It is now well-known enough (mostly through TV shows about police detectives) that people will use it to describe non-criminals as well, as in your example.