# What does M.O. mean here?

Tags: meaning, acronyms

What does mean "M.O." [here](https://www.forbes.com/sites/hanktucker/2021/04/07/florida-octogenarian-becomes-a-billionaire-after-investing-in-celsius-energy-drink/?sh=2a399c762b62)? I have found a [list of possible meanings](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/MO) for this acronym but do not know which applies.

> “Some people collect cars,” Fieldly says. “That’s not his M.O.—Carl collects businesses.”

Comment: Repeat of this question: [What does M,O stand for?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/248239/what-does-m-o-stand-for/248244#248244).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "modus operandi", a holdover phrase from Latin which means literally "mode of operation". A person's M.O. describes their habits and typical routines and behaviors.

Comment: Specifically it is a legal phrase, refering to the way that criminal commits crimes, which can be used as evidence that the same person committed a series or crimes.